# Flutter app is not running in my Android real device

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I installed Flutter with VS code as editor..

Everything is fine ..

Flutter Doctor detects that there is a connected device ..

[image]

My device is also recognised by VS code ..

[image]][2

But when I try to test app .. there is nothing .. NOTHING -_-

No errors .. no messages .. no app .. nothing ..

[image]

HEEEEEEEEELP PLZ

Comment: you tried using `flutter run` ?

Comment: does it work in the emulator ?

Comment: try opening your terminal and type "flutter run"

Comment: PS E:\flutter projects\testapp> flutter devices
1 connected device:

BLN L21 • 7BQDU17308003256 • android-arm64 • Android 7.0 (API 24)
PS E:\flutter projects\testapp> flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on BLN L21 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Comment: Did my answer help you solve your issue? If so, please mark it as correct for relevance to other users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Open the command line on the folder of your app and type `flutter devices` and check the name of your physical device on the list.
- Copy the name of the device. If it was an emulator it would something like `emulator-5554`
- Run `flutter run -d emulator-5554` (having replaced it with the name of your device).

You could also try Android Studio to test if the issue is with VScode.

Answer (score 0):

try these commands on command prompt or in the terminal of your vs code its maybe helped you much easily when you use these command lines on vs code
and the lines are
`flutter clean`
then press enter then again
`flutter pub get`
then again press
`flutter run -d Chrome`
if you want to run the app on "Chrome"
and you use the Google Chrome as you default web browser
thank you!!! ^_^
I wish that I helps you at least to use vs code better when you didn't have any emulator attached to it